# Image is not uploading to the server with REST API using PHP cURL

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

I am trying to upload image to a server via REST API. So that I used PHP cURL. But I encountered that the file is not uploading to the server end. Where am I doing wrong ? please help. Below is my code

```
<?php

$resp = "";
//check is POST
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //check image upload, your want to check for other things too like: is it an image?
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
        //make filename for new file
        $uploadfile = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        //move the upload
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$uploadfile),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------516718006976498379520930"
                ),
            ));

            $resp = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
        }
    }
    else {
        $resp = "Upload a valid image file";
    }
}
?>

    <form runat="server" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
        <div class="upload">
            <div id="upload-image">Upload Image</div>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </div>submit" name="submit" id="main" value="Match Face"></input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Stop trying to add your own Content-Type header. cURL has no idea about that boundary value you specified in there, it creates it own. You basically _lied_ to the receiver about how your data is actually structured by doing this.

Comment: Plus, you are not sending the actual file content in the first place. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$uploadfile)` - that is the local _path_ to the file only, send under the parameter name `file`. Go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php to figure out how this actually works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am learning cURL PHP and these code I get from Postman. I even added the code ```new CURLFILE```, but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, just use the below code. I hope it may work.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOTP_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => new CURLFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$uploadfile)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: @ShirshaGhosh Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you upload a file into your local and send the local address in server
in server file you must code this not in local

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
$picurl = $this->UploadPic($_FILES['file']['name']);
}
      publick function UploadPic($file){
//your uploader code here
//at the end you must return address
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes I am actually doing the same

Comment: in your api file you must pas the image to server.remove the move_uploaded_file and in ``` CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$uploadfile),``` you must code like this ```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
```